# Проблема с авторизацией на сайте для асинхронного парсинга

Tags: python, парсер, асинхронность

Одна проблема, нет авторизации на сайте, или она не проходит. Код [тут](https://pastebin.com/ERmQT5HJ), он просто не поместился в этом окне

---

В данный момент, авторизация позади, но код все равно не хочет работать сейчас он выглядит [так](https://pastebin.com/NuYtrrC1), и выходит ошибка

````
  File "/home/kukuruzka-vitya/CODE/za_python/parsing/pars_university_first/pars_asin.py", line 218, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/kukuruzka-vitya/CODE/za_python/parsing/pars_university_first/pars_asin.py", line 183, in main
    asyncio.run(gather_data())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/kukuruzka-vitya/CODE/za_python/parsing/pars_university_first/pars_asin.py", line 180, in gather_data
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "/home/kukuruzka-vitya/CODE/za_python/parsing/pars_university_first/pars_asin.py", line 53, in get_page_data
    soup = BS(src, 'lxml')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 312, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type '_RequestContextManager' has no len()
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ClientSession._request' was never awaited```
````

Comment: .post('https://api.ucheba.ru/v1/auth', headers=headers, json=auth_data)

Comment: @СергейШ Выходит ошибка 'File "/home/kukuruzka-vitya/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 364, in update_host
    raise InvalidURL(url)
aiohttp.client_exceptions.InvalidURL: api.ucheba.ru/v1/auth'

Comment: await session.post(auth_url, json=auth_data, headers=headers)

Comment: @СергейШ Сейчас код выглядит [так](https://pastebin.com/pJx2BsAr), все равно не работает - авторизация не проходит. Возможно, что авторизация проходит, но почему то не сохраняется в сессии

Comment: Добавить в headers 'Content-Type': 'application/json'.

Comment: Такая же ошибка **pages_count = soup.find('div', 'paginator mt-25').find('ul').find_all('li')[-1].text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'**

Comment: @СергейШ не знаю поможет ли это, но [тут](https://pastebin.com/Cn0MwGVv) вообще авторизация не нужна, он изначально авторизован

Comment: Есть продвижение. Я в headers добавил cookie и авторизация прошла, но появилась ошибка при попытки запустить последовательность **File "/home/kukuruzka-vitya/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 721, in __exit__
    raise asyncio.TimeoutError from None
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError
kukuruzka-vitya@kukuruzkavitya-Ins**

Comment: "но тут вообще авторизация не нужна, он изначально авторизован" нет не авторизован

Comment: @СергейШ он как то перебирает страницы  которые только авторизованный пользователь видит

Comment: Чтоб переберать страницы, на сколько я понял, авторизация не обязательна

Comment: Это хорошо, но куки все равно нужно было, а сейчас выходит ошибка которую я вообще не представляю как исправить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение данной проблемы было проще чем казалось, во первых нужно было в headers добавить cookis, а так же у меня в коде были глупые повторы некоторых строк которые и не давали работать коду

Comment: Ответ не слишкрм понятен, хотя и неким образом решает вашу проблему, не слишком хорошо описанную в вопросе.